# How to convert json objects into a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I want to be able to convert my JSON object into an array is there a built in function in php that allows me to do this?

Here is my json object:

```
in_userid: "38"
in_email: "user@email.com"
in_firstname: "John"
in_lastname: "Mason"
in_mobilenumber: "00000000000"
in_password: "pass12345"
in_phonenumber: "0000000"
```

and I want it to look something like this:

```
Array(
     in_userid => "38",
     in_email => "user@email.com",
     in_firstname => "John",
     in_lastname => "Mason",
     in_mobilenumber => "00000000000",
     in_password => "pass12345",
     in_phonenumber => "0000000",
);
```

How will I do this?

Comment: `json_decode($json, !0);`

Comment: can't you just search your title in google?

Comment: Please try to perform at least the most basic search before posting a question. This is very very basic (that in itself isn't a problem) and has been asked and answered many many times (that is a problem).

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode()`. It takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable. See the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function in the docs.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @WebChemist thanks for the advice, will definitely keep in mind for the next time.